# Adding images on both sides of a vertical video using FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a video that I recorded with my phone vertically. When viewing the video on a computer, there are large, black margins on both sides of the video. I would like to replace these with an image using FFmpeg.

I read the [section on pads](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad) on the FFmpeg docs, but it does not say anything about using images as pads (correct me if I'm wrong), it only mentions using colors.

Edit: The following command does what I want, except that I want an image and not a color: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v pad="ih*16/9:ih:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:orange" output.mp4'`

Comment: Vertical Video Syndrome. What do you want the output file width x height to be?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Aspect ratio 16:9, so it will depend on the input. I've updated the question.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Do you know how to do this? I've been trying a lot, but haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Comment: The pillarboxing you see is likely added by the player. I'm guessing it is not in the video itself. Do you have an example image or images you want to use as the "filler"?

Comment: An example would be [this one](https://s31.postimg.org/kf40jygij/image.png). Would it also be possible to have two images, one for each side?